# HTML selecting last selected dropdown value?

Tags: php, html

I'm dealing with a registration form at the moment, specifically, I'm dealing with redisplaying any information the user enters into the inputs if there is an error in the registration verification.

Normally, when a user hits 'submit' - if there is an error, the page refreshes and they are echoed out and the form is redisplayed. The problem is there is sometimes genuinely valid information in some of the fields, and by regrabbing that data, it can be redisplayed using the value attribute and the `isset()` function like so (if of course that data has been POSTed, which in this case it has):

```
<input type="email" name="anEmail" 
                   value=" <?php echo (isset($email)) ? $email : false; ?>" />
```

That works fine for the `<input>` element, but is the same achievable with a dropdown list through the `<select>` element?

I initially tried:

```
<select name="region" 
       value="<?php echo (isset($region)) ? $region : 'Auckland'; ?>" > 

<!-- with 'Auckland' being the default value of the list -->
```

However, [it doesn't seem like](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) that `value=""` is a valid attribute for the `<select>` tag.

Any ideas on how I could accomplish this? Cheers.

Comment: <select> tag dont have value attribute..

Comment: @SonalKhunt I know, I mentioned that. :)

Comment: @Antilogical, I think you should consider using Javascript to set this selects instead of making a mess server side... for example... with jQuery... `$('option[value="Auckland"]').attr('selected', 'selected');` ... you can also write functions for HTML forms... check this out... http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/Form#select

Comment: ok you know abt magic function in php you can use that...  i put my code as answer...

Answer (score 2):

```
function build_select($name, array $options = NULL, $selected = NULL)
{
    foreach($options as $value => $option)
        $return .= ($value != $selected)? '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$option.'</option>': '<option selected="selected" value="'.$value.'">'.$option.'</option>';

    return '<select name="'.$name.'">'.$return.'</select>';
}

echo build_select('region', array('Lorem' => 'Ipsum', 'Auckland' => 'Auckland', 'Ipsum' => 'Lorem'), 'Auckland');
```

HTML

```
<select name="region">
<option value="Lorem">Ipsum</option>
<option selected="selected" value="Auckland">Auckland</option>
<option value="Ipsum">Lorem</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

it's selected="selected", i think. or just "selected".

a quick example of how you might implement that:

```
case "value0":
    $selected0 = "selected";
    break;
case "value1":
    $selected1 = "selected";
    break;

<option value="value0" <?php echo $selected0;?>></option>
<option value="value1" <?php echo $selected1;?>></option>
```

Comment: it makes sense to use a switch statement in advance if you have several options.  it'll save a new comparison for each echo.

Comment: true, better than multiple if statements, but it still seems over the top for such a simple task?

Comment: i think that's quite efficient.  dont forget the swtich statement.  so, get hold of region and do switch ($region) {case etc etc}.  do double check me in a code validator if you use "selected" as opposed to 'selected="selected"'.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `selected="selected"` to specific option. Like so:

```
<select name="region">
    <option value="opt1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="opt2" selected="selected">Option 2</option>
    <option value="opt3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="opt4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

With this code Option 2 is selected

And in pehe you have to check if specific option equals the input.

```
<option value="opt4"<?php if ($region == "opt2"){ echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>>Option 4</option>
```

Comment: So there's no PHP involved if they select a different option (say opt3), and it then errors out? It still returns opt3 and not the default opt2?

Comment: Just edited my post. Yo'll have to check if current option equals with `$region` as if so the echo out `selected="selected"`

Comment: So your saying I have to do an if statement for each option? Surely there's a simpler way to do this as I have about 20 options.

Comment: Yup there is. Either to use javascript to select option or creating options dynamivly, with php. Eg. you have array with possible and then generate option wiht foreach loop. IF you need details on these options, let me know

Comment: Rajat Singhal implemented teh javascript version :)

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this if number of options are not much:
In every option put the code:

```
<select>
<option selected="<?php echo (isset($region) && $region=='Volvo') ? $region : ''; ?>">Volvo</option>
<option selected="<?php echo (isset($region) && $region=='Saab') ? $region : ''; ?>">Saab</option>
<option selected="<?php echo (isset($region) && $region=='Mercedes') ? $region : ''; ?>">Mercedes</option>
<option selected="<?php echo (isset($region) && $region=='Audi') ? $region : ''; ?>">Audi</option>
</select>
```

But if options are much in number javascript code is needed to be written..

```
if(isset($region))
{
echo '
<script>$("#id option").each(function()
{
    if($(this).val()=='.$region.')
    $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
});
</script>';
}
```

Comment: Surely that's way too much code for such a simple task. I have about 20 options in the drop down menu.

Answer (score 1):

```
function __selected($ctrlName,$value)
{
    if(isset($_REQUEST[$ctrlName]) && trim($_REQUEST[$ctrlName]) == trim($value))
        return "selected='selected'";
    else
        return false;
}
```

use like

```
<select name="cmbCondition">
                                    <option value="Excellent" <?php echo __selected('cmbCondition',"Excellent")?>>Excellent</option>
                                    <option value="Good" <?php echo __selected('cmbCondition',"Good")?>>Good</option>
                                    <option value="Poor" <?php echo __selected('cmbCondition',"Poor")?>>Poor</option>          
                                </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamiclly creating options basod on array.
Usage should be pretty straightforward.

```
<?php

function rennder_options($options = array(), $selection = null) {

    if (!is_array($options)) {
        return false;
    }
    $result = "";
    foreach($option as $option) {
        $option_str =  '<option value="'.$option['value'].'"';
        if ($selection !== null && $option['value'] == $selection){
            $option_str .= ' selected="selected"';
        }
        $option_str .= '>'.$option['name'].'</option>';
        $result .= $option_str;
    }
    return result;
}

$options = array(
    array( "value" => "opt1", "name" => "Option 1" )
    array( "value" => "opt2", "name" => "Option 2" ),
    array( "value" => "opt3", "name" => "Option 3" ),
);

?>
<select name="region">
<?php echo render_options($options, $_POST['region']); ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Lol you've changed your answer several times :)